# SVG - make viewBox(0, 0, 100%, 100%) with percentages

Tags: javascript, css, svg

How can I make SVG viewBox user coordinate system the same as the viewport coordinates system provided by SVG itself (height="100%" and width="100%")?

I need this special case for a project I'm doing, SVG element should be responsive, but still we need to keep height and width 100% on the SVG itself.

So, I need something like this:

```
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0, 0, 100%, 100%">
  <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20" stroke="black" strokeWidth="1" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

.. but the viewBox attribute doesn't accept percentages.

Comment: The `viewBox` attribute simply sets the maximum `x` and `y` coordinates of your graphic's internal coordinate system, which will then be stretched to the size you specify in `width` and `height`. Long story short, just use `viewBox="0 0 100 100"` and you can use numbers between 0 and 100.

Comment: @MátéSafranka not completely right, whether stretching happens depends on the value of the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute. As a default, it won't. @TamaraJovic, the answer to the question depends on what "responsive" behavior you want. Please describe what should happen when the SVG resizes: should the circle remain a circle, or be stretched/shrinked to an ellipse?

Answer (score 32):

%/px is not allowed in the viewBox, those are the maximum coordinates.

By default the SVG content is contained to the SVG size.

If you want the content to stretch to 100%, disable the aspect ratio using `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.

You can also use `preserveAspectRatio="slice"` to make the content cover the SVG (like `background-size: cover`).

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
```

There are some good articles about this: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/ and https://alligator.io/svg/preserve-aspect-ratio/

Comment: However viewBox="0 0 100 100" could crop the image if its intrinsics dimensione are greater than 100px.  I think could be better set viewBox to values greater than 100

Comment: The possibility of using percentages in viewBox would have been really cool :(

Comment: @aderchox The elements inside an svg are absolute positioned with x and y co-ordinates. How can you determine the viewbox in percentage when the internal co-ordinate system is absolute numbers? I guess you mean 100% width would be the x + width value of the right-most element in the svg?